# Install Windows 10 on a device that doesn't have an operating system?

Tags: windows-10, bios, operating-systems

I have brought a computer from a factory company on eBay but it doesn't have an operating system.

How do I install windows 10 on a device that doesn't have an operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10)
2. Double-click the *MediaCreationToolxxxx.exe* file to launch the tool
3. Click the *Accept* button to agree to the Microsoft terms
4. Select the *Create installation media (USB flash drive, DVD, or ISO file) for another PC option*
5. Click the *Next* button
6. Clear the *Use the recommended options for this PC option (if applicable)* and select the correct language, architecture, and edition of Windows 10
7. Click the *Next* button
8. Select the USB flash drive option
9. Click the *Next* button
10. Select the removable drive from the list (If you don't see the drive, click the *Refresh drive list* option)
11. Click the *Next* button.
12. Click the *Finish* button
13. Remove the USB-Stick
14. Plug the USB-Stick into the device without the operating system
15. Go into the BIOS (by pressing F8, F10, F12, DEL etc. (depends on the manufacturer) on startup)
16. Boot from your USB-Stick
17. Go through the Windows-Setup

Comment: How would I boot it through to the windows setup?

Comment: @T.E I edited the answer

Comment: @T.E Created installation media is bootable. Set proper boot device in BIOS settings (or use bootmenu to select it - F8 in most BIOSes).

Comment: What options would I need to press when iam on the boot menu?

Comment: @T.E Override Boot and choose your USB-Stick